# What is the correct way to calculate Mean across all variables by grouping

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

```
A <- data %>% 
      group_by(Agent) %>%
      summarise(across(EP:Yt.ha),mean)
```

The Error message is

Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..2`.
x Input `..2` must be a vector, not a function.
i Input `..2` is `mean`.
i The error occured in group 1: Agent = "Hydro".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

I remember doing it by this way longback but I believe that now I must have misplaced some functions or code. Can someone tell the correct way? There are 13 variable across EP to Yt.ha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this ( you can add group by conditions):

```
# install if not already
install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = T)

# load package
library(tidyverse)

# load data
data(iris)
iris

# find the mean, grouped by species
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(across(Petal.Width:Sepal.Length, ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))

# alternate way to find the mean for specific cols (using col index numbers)
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(across(c(1, 3:4), ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: In above, i used first, third and fourth columns in the iris dataset to find out the respective averages.

Answer (score 1):

In case you never found out. The brackets at the end were set incorrectly. Here is how it works:

```
A <- data %>% group_by(Agent) %>% summarise(across(EP:Yt.ha, mean))
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better with reproducible code.

I would suggest something along the lines of:

```
data <- iris

output <- data %>%
          group_by(species) %>%
          summarise(across(petal.width:sepal.length),mean)

// or 

output <- data %>%
          group_by(species) %>%
          summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean))
```

Comment: The first idea didn`t work. The second worked however I want across only few vairables of my choice

Comment: Then use `across(var())`